# Why automatic deploy in Play Framework 2.5 takes so long?

Tags: java, deployment, playframework

I have started to create an application using the play framework 2.5, my operative system is windows 10. It is very useful that play make automatic deployment when there is a change in the source code, but when I change the code, it takes a very long time to apply the changes, what could be the reason and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you save a change and reload your web page, Play recompiles your application's source code in bytecode (.class) and then restarts the server. 
Even if the compilation process is incremental (if you edit a single class, it will recompile it only) the Scala compiler is not as fast as an interpreted language such as Python or PHP (but it produces a better optimized and type safe code).

If you want to speed up the development workflow, you can launch your application using "activator ~run" instead of "activator run". By doing this, Play will directly recompile your application each time you SAVE a change (no need to refresh your web page).